# Unable to receive results from MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, cloud

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my code isn't letting me get the documents that are hosted in my MongoDB Atlas cluster. I've made a small example that has the same problem I'm experiencing.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

class App {
    init(): void {
        this.connect();
        this.query();
    }

    private connect(): void {
        mongoose.connect('<the string MongoDB Atlas gave me>', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    query(): void {
        let Drawing = mongoose.model('Drawing',
            new Schema({ name: String, tags: [String], data: String }),
            'drawings');

        Drawing.find({}, (err, res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}

let app = new App();
app.init()
```

The output of console.log(res) is

```
[]
```

On MongoDB Atlas, I've whitelisted the correct ip, created a cluster and setup access to it, then made a database called testdb that has a "drawings" collection with the following document sample:

```
{   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5e6042af1c9d440000f0341b"

},
   "name":"Cat",
   "tags":[
      "animal",
      "cute"

],
   "data":"hadlkahdwlh28ueu2097094527dhaskdhak"
}
```

Comment: Did you check the Db name in connection string is `testdb` ?

Comment: You might have something, connection string format is as follows:

mongodb+srv//myuser:mypassword@clusterurl.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: That was it! final url is as follows:
mongodb+srv//myuser:mypassword@clusterurl.azure.mongodb.net/testdb